# Can I solve blurry text on an old computer monitor?

Tags: display

I was given an old (box-like) monitor (Flatron 775FT), and it's better than my current one as far as differentiating shades of black goes. The only problem is that the text is a bit blurry... Is there a way to solve this?

**edit:**
It's only blurry near the right and left edges of the screen..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A CRT can be blury if the grid becomes magnetized. If your monitor has a degauss control, then activating it will fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah I tampered with something called degauss.. No improvement.

Answer (score 1):

i found an archive at [this website](http://fileshare.eshop.bg/index.php?what=search2&searchstring=Flatron+795FT+Plus), containing various manuals, schematic diagrams (PDFs) and an 'adjustment program' for the LG Flatron 775 FT

the archive is split in 4 parts (RAR), look for **Flatron 775FTFB775BC.part1.rar** and the 3 following parts, download is free.

hope this helps.

Comment: Looks good, I'll check the link out when I get a second or more.